# Oracle regular expression substring - Extract number after dollar sign

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have following table and rows:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    column_name_1   VARCHAR2(400)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (paragrap_typos) VALUES ('More than $78.35 billion. That is great.');
INSERT INTO my_table (paragrap_typos) VALUES ('Another $60 billion. Good Luck');
INSERT INTO my_table (paragrap_typos) VALUES ('Incomes up to $626,000. Nice');
INSERT INTO my_table (paragrap_typos) VALUES ('This is budget $ 27 million, seems fine');
INSERT INTO my_table (paragrap_typos) VALUES ('Savings of nearly $10,345 ave a nice day');
```

Kindly help to write sql query using regular expression to get following output:

```
$78.35 billion
$60 billion
$626,000
$ 27 million
$10,345
```

Would be thankful.

Comment: Are `million` and `billion` the only words that follow numbers that should be preserved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         column_name_1,
         '\$\s*\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?(\s+(hundred|thousand|million|billion))?',
         1,
         1,
         'i'
       ) AS value
FROM   my_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( column_name_1 ) AS
SELECT 'More than $78.35 billion. That is great.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Another $60 billion. Good Luck' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Incomes up to $626,000. Nice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is budget $ 27 million, seems fine' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Savings of nearly $10,345 ave a nice day' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| $78.35 billion |
| $60 billion |
| $626,000 |
| $ 27 million |
| $10,345 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cmeg3H_b)